# Kendoui Multiselect show text values selected on tooltip

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a problem, I like to show a select **text** values of a MultiSelect control on a **tooltip**.
I only can show the value(numeric) from MultiSelect, this is my code:

```
var multiselect = $("#combo_multi").data("kendoMultiSelect");

value2 = multiselect.value(); //show only numeric values ->14376, etc.
```

Show the numeric values together without spaces. ->14376

I like to show the **text** value, not the numeric value.
I think I have to use an array for show the text value, but I don´t know how do it.
If somebody have the response of this problem, I appreciate the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you a bit

```
var multiselect = $("#combo_multi").data("kendoMultiSelect");
var value2 = multiselect.value();
var selectedValues = value2.split(",");

var multiSelectData = multiselect.dataSource.data();

for (var i = 0; i < multiSelectData.length; i++) {
    var numberValue = multiSelectData[i].number;
    for (var j = 0; j < selectedValues.length; j++) {
        if (selectedValues[j] == numberValue) {
            // here we get description for value
            var desc = multiSelectData[i].description;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Japi, I have an error on var selectedValues = value2.split(","); -> undefined, I need make some test

Comment: If value2 is comma separated string, split method should work. You can check it with <code> console.log( value2 ); </code>

Comment: Not sure how much things have changed since you wrote this in 2014, but the multiselect.value(); already comes back in the correct format, you don't need to call split (it is not a comma separated string).

Answer (score 1):

Example other

```
$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect();
var multiselect = $("#CityTo").data("kendoMultiSelect");
var dataItem = multiselect.dataItems();

//***Debug

var CityArray = new Array();
CityArray = dataItem;
alert(JSON.stringify(CityArray));

//***End Debug

//**************** Applied example

var newHtml = "";
var item = dataItem;
$.each(item, function (index, item) {
newHtml += '<div class="panel panel-default" ><div class="panel-heading">' + item.City_Name + '</div><div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div></div>';
});

$("#CityCount").html(newHtml);
```

You can see the details "dataItem" using "item."

item.City_Name

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a newer version of Kendo UI so possibly things have changed since you asked this. I'll give you an updated answer..

```
var multiselect = $("#combo_multi").data("kendoMultiSelect");
var selectedValues = multiselect.value();
var multiSelectData = multiselect.dataSource.data();
var count = selectedValues.length;
for (var i = 0; i < multiSelectData.length; i++) {
        if (selectedValues.indexOf(multiSelectData[i].Value) >= 0 ) {
                //found, do something
                var selectedText = multiSelectData[i].Text;
                count--;
        }
        if (count == 0) {
             break;
        }
}
```

Comment: if you want to keep all selected text in an array:
var selectedText = [];
then inisde if loop replace with this
selectedText.push(multiSelectData[i].Text);
if you need it back to string later? var selectedTextString = String(selectedText);